# Вставить номер в список чтобы он оставался отсортированным

Tags: python, list

Нельзя использовать метод sort() и другие функции. Помогите советом

```
def nr_into(nr: int, num_list: list) -> list:
    """
    Return a list of numbers where the "nr" is added into the "num_list" so that the list keep going to be sorted.

    Built-in sort methods are not allowed.

    nr_into(5, []) -> [5]
    nr_into(5, [1,2,3,4]) -> [1,2,3,4,5]
    nr_into(5, [1,2,3,4,5,6]) -> [1,2,3,4,5,5,6]
    nr_into(0, [1,2,3,4,5]) -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,]

    """
```

Comment: Каким именно советом? Ну используй insert().

Comment: bisect.insort(a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a))
https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def nr_into(nr, num_list):
    for i, (p, n) in enumerate(zip([float('-inf')] + num_list, num_list + [float('inf')])):
        if p < nr <= n:
            num_list.insert(i, nr)
            break
    return num_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nr_into(nr: int, num_list: list) -> list:
    c = len(num_list)
    if len(num_list) == 0:
        num_list.append(nr)
    else:
        for i in range(len(num_list)):
            if nr > num_list[i]:
                c -= 1
                if c == 0:
                    num_list.append(nr)
                continue
            else:
                num_list.insert(i, nr)
                break
    return num_list
```